# How to transpose a sparse matrix in cuSparse?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to compute `A^TA` using cuSparse. `A` is a large but sparse matrix. The proper function to use based on the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#csrgemm2) is `cusparseDcsrgemm2`. However, this is one of the few cuSparse operations that doesn't support an optional built-in transpose for the input matrix. There's a line in the documentation that said

> Only the NN version is supported. For other modes, the user has to
>   transpose A or B explicitly.

The problem is I couldn't find a function in cuSparse that can perform a transpose. I know I can transpose in CPU and copy it to the GPU but that will slow down the application. Am I missing something? What is the right way to use cuSparse to compute `A^TA`?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#csr2cscEx2

Comment: @RobertCrovella you are right... csc is the transpose of csr. If you write an answer I will accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For matrices that are in CSR (or CSC) format:

The CSR sparse representation of a matrix has identical format/memory layout as the CSC sparse representation of its transpose.

Therefore, if we use the [cusparse provided function to convert a CSR format matrix into a CSC format](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#csr2cscEx2), that resultant CSC-format matrix is actually the same as the CSR representation of the transpose of the original matrix.  Therefore this CSR-to-CSC conversion routine could be used to find the transpose of a CSR format sparse matrix.  (It can similarly be used to find the transpose of a CSC format sparse matrix.)